# Displaying previously submitted location points in a webform

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I'm designing a Survey123 webform for respondents to identify points along a route, one by one, to essentially submit the full sequence of points along a route so that a transport service can then be mapped.

I've the form set up so that each time a location is submitted with the geopoint widget, the respondent has the option of returning to a certain point in the webform so that they can add the next point in the sequence until they have provided all locations

One of the feedback points i am consistently getting is that when the respondent is using the form to input data points, the point will be submited on completing the form each time and 'wiped' on the respondents end each time so that there is no record on the map of points that they have already added to the survey.

If the respondents will not have their own named user Survey123 accounts and will just be accessing the public webform through the URL i'll be providing, is there any way for the survey webform to keep record and display points that they themselves have previously submitted so that they can follow what they've already entered, where they are along the route, where they have yet to drop a point etc.?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you collecting multiple points in a single survey, and want to be able to see the points collected so far in that survey (even if the survey itself has not yet been submitted), OR are you wanting the current survey to display points collected from previously submitted surveys?

Comment: It's closer to the former i think. So there will be numerous people filling out the form, each person having to provide many points when they are filling it out and it would be perhaps less confusing if they could see points they have just entered.

However, and this may be where it becomes impossible to control if all respondents are filling in via the web version and not the app as users with named accounts, i don't think respondents should be able to see points previously submitted by other respondents; that may have implications for GDPR.